# Asking an advise about Pivot Table

Tags: laravel, database-design, model, pivot, pivot-table

I have 3 tables like this

Student:
id |  name

```php
class Student extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'students';

    public function marks () {
        return $this->belongsToMany( 'App\Models\Subject', 'marks' )->using( 'App\Models\Mark');
    }
}
```

Subject:
id | name

```php
class Subject extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'subjects';

    public function marks () {
        return $this->belongsToMany( 'App\Models\Student', 'marks' )->using( 'App\Models\Mark');
    }
}
```

Mark:
subject_id | student_id | type_of_exam | times_taking_exam | mark

```php
class Mark extends Pivot
{
    protected $table = 'marks';
    public function student() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Student','student_id');
    }
    public function subject() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Student','subject_id');
    }
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

The table Mark which has 4 column primary key (id_subject, id_student, type_of_exam, times_taking_exam)

**I don't know my design database is correct or not, but if it did**, how can I use sync to update or insert mark for my student.
Because I understand that the method ***sync*** is like this:

```php
$student->marks()->sync([
    $subject_id => [
        'type_of_exam' => 1,
        'times_taking_exam' => 1,
        'mark' => 10,
    ]
]);
```

But it is not correct for this situation cause it will run this code like this:

```php
Mark::updateOrCreate( [
    'student_id' => $student_id,
    'subject_id'  => $subject_id,
], [
    'type_of_exam' => 1,
    'times_taking_exam' => 1,
    'mark' => 10
] );
```

Instead, I want this:

```php
Mark::updateOrCreate( [
    'student_id' => $student_id,
    'subject_id' => $subject_id,
    'type_of_exam'  => 1,
    'times_taking_exam' => 1,
], [
    'mark' => 10
] );
```

I have tried use Mark as Model but I think it's not the best way.

Comment: For starters, your pivot model is `MarksAdvanced`, so that's the model that should be in `using` method, and I dont think pivot model would have relationship methods.

Comment: Also, you say in table `id_subject, id_student` but references student_id and subject_id in relationship methods. And, Marks class, judging from the attributes, should actually be a normal model